# JPA Embeddable binding fields and setVisibleColumns in a table?

Tags: java, jpa, vaadin, vaadin7

I'm trying `setVisibleColumns()` in my table to display values of `@Embeddable` class. I have two class Nucleo and Endereco. Endereco is an Embeddable class and Nucleo uses Endereco. 
Trying setVisibleColumns of a table returns some exceptions and I don't know how to solve that.

Other question, how to I can use BeanFieldGroup with this Embeddable class.

I'm trying this.

```
@Entity
public class Nucleo {

    @Id @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @NotNull @NotEmpty @Size(min=3, max=50) @Column(unique=true)
    private String descricao;

    //embedded
    private Endereco endereco;

    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.LAZY) 
    @JoinColumn(name="id_unidadeescolar")
    private UnidadeEscolar unidadeEscolar;

    public Nucleo() {
        this(0L, "", null);
    }

    public Nucleo(Long id, String descricao, Endereco endereco) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.descricao = descricao;
        this.endereco = endereco;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getDescricao() {
        return descricao;
    }

    public void setDescricao(String descricao) {
        this.descricao = descricao;
    }

    public Endereco getEndereco() {
        return endereco;
    }

    public void setEndereco(Endereco endereco) {
        this.endereco = endereco;
    }

    public UnidadeEscolar getUnidadeEscolar() {
        return unidadeEscolar;
    }

    public void setUnidadeEscolar(UnidadeEscolar unidadeEscolar) {
        this.unidadeEscolar = unidadeEscolar;
    }
}


@Embeddable
public class Endereco {

    private String endereco;
    private Integer numero;
    private String complemento;
    private String bairro;
    private String cidade;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private EstadosDoBrasil uf;

    private String cep;

    public Endereco() {
        this("", 0, "",
             "", EstadosDoBrasil.AC, "");
    }

    public Endereco(String endereco, Integer numero, String complemento,
            String bairro, EstadosDoBrasil uf, String cep) {
        super();
        this.endereco = endereco;
        this.numero = numero;
        this.complemento = complemento;
        this.bairro = bairro;
        this.uf = uf;
        this.cep = cep;
    }

    public String getEndereco() {
        return endereco;
    }

    public void setEndereco(String endereco) {
        this.endereco = endereco;
    }

    public Integer getNumero() {
        return numero;
    }

    public void setNumero(Integer numero) {
        this.numero = numero;
    }

    public String getComplemento() {
        return complemento;
    }

    public void setComplemento(String complemento) {
        this.complemento = complemento;
    }

    public String getBairro() {
        return bairro;
    }

    public void setBairro(String bairro) {
        this.bairro = bairro;
    }

    public EstadosDoBrasil getUf() {
        return uf;
    }

    public void setUf(EstadosDoBrasil uf) {
        this.uf = uf;
    }

    public String getCep() {
        return cep;
    }

    public void setCep(String cep) {
        this.cep = cep;
    }   
}


//view
Table tabela = new Table("", datasource){
            @Override
            protected String formatPropertyValue(Object rowId,Object colId, Property<?> property) {                 
                if(property.getType() == Long.class){
                    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("00000");
                    return df.format((Long)property.getValue());
                }               
                return super.formatPropertyValue(rowId, colId, property);
            }
        };
        tabela.setSelectable(true);
        tabela.setVisibleColumns(new Object[]{"id","descricao", "unidadeEscolar.nome", "endereco.cidade", "endereco.uf"});
        tabela.setColumnHeaders(new String[] {"#","Descrição", "Unidade escolar", "Cidade", "UF"}); 
        tabela.addItemClickListener(this);
        tabela.setColumnWidth("id", 50);
        tabela.setColumnWidth("descricao", 200);
        //tabela.setColumnWidth("unidadeEscolar.nome", 200);
        //tabela.setColumnWidth("endereco.cidade", 200);
        //tabela.setColumnWidth("endereco.uf", 25);
        tabela.setSizeFull();
        mainLayout.addComponent(tabela);
```

Vaadin book chap:**9.4.5. Binding Fields to a Bean**, there an exemplo to use `buildAndBind("Street", "address.street")`, I tried follow this example and add `endereco.cidade` and returns an exception.

Tried

```
field = binder.buildAndBind("Cidade:", "endereco.cidade", TextUpper.class);
        cidade = (TextUpper)field;
        cidade.setWidth("5cm");
        cidade.setMaxLength(50);
        mainLayout.addComponent(cidade);
```

//exception

```
ago 08, 2014 3:02:30 AM com.vaadin.server.DefaultErrorHandler doDefault
GRAVE: 
com.vaadin.server.ServerRpcManager$RpcInvocationException: Unable to invoke method click in com.vaadin.shared.ui.button.ButtonServerRpc
    at com.vaadin.server.ServerRpcManager.applyInvocation(ServerRpcManager.java:170)
    at com.vaadin.server.ServerRpcManager.applyInvocation(ServerRpcManager.java:118)
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleBurst(ServerRpcHandler.java:207)
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleRpc(ServerRpcHandler.java:111)
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.UidlRequestHandler.synchronizedHandleRequest(UidlRequestHandler.java:91)
    at com.vaadin.server.SynchronizedRequestHandler.handleRequest(SynchronizedRequestHandler.java:37)
    at com.vaadin.server.VaadinService.handleRequest(VaadinService.java:1382)
    at com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:238)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:136)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:526)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1078)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:655)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1566)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1523)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.vaadin.server.ServerRpcManager.applyInvocation(ServerRpcManager.java:168)
    ... 30 more
Caused by: com.vaadin.event.ListenerMethod$MethodException: Invocation of method buttonClick in br.com.webapp.views.NucleoView failed.
    at com.vaadin.event.ListenerMethod.receiveEvent(ListenerMethod.java:528)
    at com.vaadin.event.EventRouter.fireEvent(EventRouter.java:198)
    at com.vaadin.event.EventRouter.fireEvent(EventRouter.java:161)
    at com.vaadin.server.AbstractClientConnector.fireEvent(AbstractClientConnector.java:969)
    at com.vaadin.ui.Button.fireClick(Button.java:368)
    at com.vaadin.ui.Button$1.click(Button.java:57)
    ... 35 more
Caused by: com.vaadin.data.fieldgroup.FieldGroup$BindException: Property type for 'endereco.cidade' could not be determined. No property with that id was found.
    at com.vaadin.data.fieldgroup.FieldGroup.getPropertyType(FieldGroup.java:369)
    at com.vaadin.data.fieldgroup.BeanFieldGroup.getPropertyType(BeanFieldGroup.java:42)
    at com.vaadin.data.fieldgroup.FieldGroup.buildAndBind(FieldGroup.java:1037)
    at br.com.webapp.views.NucleoForm.bindingFields(NucleoForm.java:162)
    at br.com.webapp.views.NucleoForm.insert(NucleoForm.java:82)
    at br.com.webapp.views.NucleoView.buttonClick(NucleoView.java:131)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.vaadin.event.ListenerMethod.receiveEvent(ListenerMethod.java:508)
    ... 40 more
```

Comment: There is no getter for your `cidade` property in your `Endereco` class.

Comment: @nexus yes, I added `cidade` getter/setter. `setVisibleColumns(new Object[]{"endereco.cidade"});` returns this exception: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Ids must exist in the Container or as a generated column, missing id: endereco.cidade
 at com.vaadin.ui.Table.setVisibleColumns(Table.java:653)`

Comment: @nexus to BeanFieldGroup `buildAndBind("Cidade:", "endereco.cidade", TextUpper.class);` return this exception: `Caused by: com.vaadin.data.fieldgroup.FieldGroup$BindException: Property type for 'endereco.cidade' could not be determined. No property with that id was found.
 at com.vaadin.data.fieldgroup.FieldGroup.getPropertyType(FieldGroup.java:369)
 at com.vaadin.data.fieldgroup.BeanFieldGroup.getPropertyType(BeanFieldGroup.java:42)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The message of your exception is:

```
> Ids must exist in the Container or as a generated column, missing id:
> endereco.cidade
```

That exception is thrown because your container (assuming it's a `BeanItemContainer`) only added the properties of your `Nucleo` class. The property 'endereco' is another class and it's properties are not added to your container.

If you later need other properties of your `Endereco` class you could add all properties of it to your container:

```
datasource.addNestedContainerBean("endereco");
```

or you could just add your cidade property.

```
datasource.addNestedContainerProperty("endereco.cidade");
```

Comment: thanks !!! now works with `datasource.addNestedContainerProperty("endereco.cidade");` with `datasource.addNestedContainerBean("endereco");` doesn't and Eclipse no have autocomplete to this method. About BeanFieldGroup what do you suggest ?

Comment: @FernandoPaiva what kind of container is your datasource?

Comment: `private CustomJPAContainer<Nucleo> datasource;`

Comment: using `binder.bind(new TextField(), "endereco.cidade");` it works but using `binder.buildAndBind("Cidade", "endereco.cidade");` isn't work. Do you know why ?

Comment: @FernandoPaiva to add all properties from a nested entity using JPAContainer you can use the * wildcard for example, "endereco.*".
What kind of exception is thrown when you try to invoke binder.buildAndBind("Cidade", "endereco.cidade"); ?